# SetupProxy file not being read in Create React App Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I have this code using `CRA --template typescript` in `setupProxy.js` file

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    '/user/try',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:8002',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

but the problem is that `setupProxy.js` file is completely ignored causing my request to fail.

I know I can use the `"proxy": "http://localhost:8002"` in `package.json` but it will not accept multiple proxies.

To further test, I also created a new `CRA` but **without typescript** and suddenly it's working with the same code above.

Is there a way to make `setupProxy.js` work in **CRA typescript**?

Comment: Hi, any workaround or solution about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to just add this to your tsconfig.json. Hope it works for you.

```
"exclude": ["src/setupProxy.js"]
```